# How do you handle updating a PR on GitHub after something has been merged into master BEFORE your PR?

Tags: github, pull-request

The problem I have is as follows:

1. I rebase locally, push changes to remote and open a PR
2. While the review is in progress, some other review is finished and those changes are merged into master
3. My PR is now behind the master and the only way I can update it is to rebase it locally and force push the changes, which GitHub generally warns us to avoid, but specifically, the only issue we have is that we can't use "Show changes since your last review" - the issue I need to solve.

As far as I'm aware, there are three possible solutions:

1. There is a way I am not aware of to rebase my PR via the GitHub interface and then pull it locally, which helps with this issue
2. I should move to an alternative, e.g. GitLab - not an option in my case
3. Something third I have no clue about :D